# "git submodule update --init --recursive" keeps prompting me for password

Tags: git, macos, github, ssh, macos-mojave

I'm using Mac OS X and GitHub, and I set up Git and my SSH keys as instructed by GitHub's [Set Up](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) Git page.
I've also added the github SSH key to my Mac OS X keychain, as mentioned on [GitHub's SSH key passphrases page](https://help.github.com/en/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases). My public key is registered with Git.

As soon as i get into the directory and try to update the submodules by using "git submodule update --init --recursive",
i get this

`"Enter passphrase for key '/Users/foo-username/.ssh/id_rsa': Enter passphrase for key '/Users/foo-username/.ssh/id_rsa': Enter passphrase for key '/Users/foo-username/.ssh/id_rsa':"`

the one above is three times at once and not like this

```
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/foo-username/.ssh/id_rsa':
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/foo-username/.ssh/id_rsa':
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/foo-username/.ssh/id_rsa':
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/foo-username/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

where each time i can enter a password to authenticate,
after trying for a while i just get the error message and it re-tires to update which eventually fails.

PS: I have tried `ssh -T git@github.com` and it says  "Hi foo-username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access."

Comment: I had this problem too recently. I tried `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa` and while it wasn't a permanent fix (as in, I had to do it again later), it worked for what I needed in the moment. (Docs [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent).)

Comment: Debug this with just one submodule. `cd` into a submodule directory and run `git fetch`. Does it ask for the passphrase? What does show `git remote -v show`?

Comment: Did you add `UseKeychain yes` to your SSH configuration as mentioned in [the documentation](https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent)?

Comment: @bk2204 Yes i did add `UseKeychain yes` also this problem is only for that specific submodule and does not occur when i try elsewhere.

Comment: @phd Yes when i traverse into the submodule and try `git fetch` it does ask for the passphrase.
When i execute `git remote -v` it shows the git repos from where i push and pull

`origin git@github.com:company/submodule-repo.git (fetch)` .          
`origin git@github.com:company/submodule-repo.git (push)`

Comment: @ladygremlin thanks as of now i just kept trying and a couple of hours later it just fixed itself and updated itself.....will try it the next time